# How can I get all categories in dbpedia?

Tags: c#, uri, sparql, dbpedia, spotlight-dbpedia

I'm using the DBPediaSpotLight library and trying to get uri for each word in dbpedia like:

> Word: teach
>
> the URI is: http//dbpedia.org/resource/Teacher
>
> the Category: /business/job_title

and I want to get all sub-categories for the word "teach" (3) levels.. I'm try to look for query in sparql but I didn't find what I want.

Comment: http://dbpedia.org/resource/Teacher isn't a DBpedia category.  What exactly are you trying to get sub-categories of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://dbpedia.org/resource/Teacher (abbreviated dbpedia:Teacher) isn't a category in DBpedia, so it doesn't really make sense to ask for subcategories of it.  However, [http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Teaching](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category%3aTeaching) *is* a category, and does have sub-categories.  DBpedia organizes categories using the skos:broader property.  Each supercategory is skos:broader than its subcategories.  To get its subcategories, up to three levels deep, you can use a query like this:

```
select distinct ?subcategory where {
  category:Teaching skos:broader?/skos:broader?/skos:broader ?subcategory
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20?subcategory%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20category%3aTeaching%20skos%3abroader?/skos%3abroader?/skos%3abroader%20?subcategory%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

A property path with a `/` means one property path followed by another.  A question mark after a property path means 0 or 1 occurrence of the path.  Thus the path

```
skos:broader?/skos:broader?/skos:broader
```

means (0 or 1 broader)/(0 or 1 broader)/broader, which means that you'll find links between Teaching and subcategories 1, 2, or 3 broader links away.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar to fetch all social event types. I found the category "Social_events" which has subcategories with actual social event types that I think they are what I need. I tried to do something similar with your example, but it displays weird data - 
`select distinct ?subcategory where {
  category:Social_events skos:broader?/skos:broader?/skos:broader ?subcategory
}`

Comment: [Sparql query result](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+distinct+%3Fsubcategory+where+%7B%0D%0A++category%3ASocial_events+skos%3Abroader%3F%2Fskos%3Abroader%3F%2Fskos%3Abroader+%3Fsubcategory%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: I've tried to run the above query on "Teaching" on DBPedia SPARQL but I only get empty results. Anyone know if the query syntax has changed?

Comment: @istewart the query syntax hasn't changed, but Dbpedia has changed some of its default prefixes on that endpoint, so that might have an effect.

Comment: @istewart eg, I see the error,  "Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 4: Undefined namespace prefix at 'category' before 'skos:broader'". You'll perhaps need to add prefix definitions.

Comment: Resolved: I did not define the "skos" prefix correctly. Thanks!